# How do I associate file types in VS Setup project with a condition?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, conditional-statements, setup-project, file-type

I need to ask for user's permission to change video and audio file associations on their computer, so I added a checkbox UI to the setup project in VS2010. My problem is that I don't see a condition for file type associations in the relevant editor to link to the checkbox property.

Doesn't VS setup and deployment project provide this functionality? Any ideas?

EDIT:

It was pointed out that Visual Studio setup projects don't have an option for conditional file associations. I am now using Orca to edit the .msi tables directly. Has anyone been able to introduce conditions for file type associations by modifying the Condition table of the .msi package, or something like that? How am I supposed to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Installer doesn't support conditional file associations.

So a solution would be to use a custom action to create them instead of the native support. You can then condition this custom action with your checkbox property.